# Downgrade flavor of instance in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am using pike version of Openstack installed through kolla. I have created an instance. I want to downgrade its flavor like from large to small. However, while resizing from horizon, I am not able to do. Also, while in Rocky setup it was successful. Hence, if anyone can tell me whether flavor downgrade is possible in pike openstack?

This is the flavor list which I am using.

```
 Name      |   RAM | Disk | Ephemeral | VCPUs 
-----------+-------+------+-----------+-------
 m1.tiny   |   512 |    1 |         0 |     1 
 m1.small  |  2048 |   20 |         0 |     1 
 m1.medium |  4096 |   40 |         0 |     2 
 m1.large  |  8192 |   80 |         0 |     4 
 m1.xlarge | 16384 |  160 |         0 |     8
```

Comment: In what respect is the new flavor smaller?  Less memory?  Fewer VCPUs?  Smaller root disk?  Other things?

Comment: I have added the flavor list which I am using.
Also, is there any settings available where you can set permission for not allowing downgrade or something?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having problems downsizing is that you would be down-sizing the root file system.  As far as I am aware, Openstack is not able to do that.

Think about it.

- Openstack doesn't know what is in the instance's root disk.  All it knows is that it is a bunch of disk blocks.  It doesn't know what the file system type ... or even if it is a recognizable file system on there at all.
- If you "resize" a bunch of disk blocks, at best you lose whatever data was in some of the blocks; e.g. at one end of the disk image.  At worst, you get a corrupted or unbootable file system.

If you are in this situation then probably need to something like this:

1. Shut down your instance.
2. Snapshot it.
3. Download the image from Glance as an ISO
4. Attach the copied ISO to a system; e.g. via a loopback driver
5. Use resize2fs to resize the file system; see https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196333
6. Upload the shrunken image to Glance, setting the metadata to match the new size.
7. Boot new instance from image with the smaller flavor.

If you have infrastructure level access, you can possibly avoid the download / upload.  There may be other ways to do the resizing.  However, the "resize2fs" command is doing things like compacting the file system and changing the partition tables.  Your alternative needs to do the equivalent.

Note: if you are using LVM, you need to resize the filesystem within the logical volume and adjust the logical volume before you do the physical volume.